# Invokescript() returns System._Comobject

Tags: javascript, c#, webbrowser-control

I am trying to get a variable(object) from a script in html page.
But on the C# code it returns System._comobject. How can i read this object?

JS code:

```
var videoUrls ={};
function test(){


var typea= ytplayer.config.args.url_encoded_fmt_stream_map.split(',');
for (var item=0; item<typea.length; item++){
  var obj= {};
  var typeb= typea[item].split('&');
  for (var param=0; param<typeb.length; param++){

     typeb[param]= typeb[param].split('=');
    obj[typeb[param][0]] = decodeURIComponent(typeb[param][1]);

  }

videoUrls[obj.quality]= obj;
}
}
```

C#:

```
browseme.Document.InvokeScript("test");
var result = browseme.Document.InvokeScript("eval", new object[] { "videoUrls" });
```

In short, what I am trying to do this, run the "test" function then get the "videoUrls". and read its contents.

How the variable output looks like in browser console.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The code sample and comments at the following link may be helpful for you to troubleshoot:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc491132(v=vs.110).aspx

'HTH,